# How does react router handle url change without causing the browser to request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

As far as I understand, until now frontend frameworks like Angular JS, Backbone JS were making use of the hash value. But react router doesn't necessarily need hash. Can someone explain me how does this work ?

I guess this must be simple, maybe preventing the default behavior on change of the URL.

I have no clue !

Comment: It puts `preventDefault()` calls on all click events on anchors. That's why you have to use its `<Link>` component. See [source](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js).

Comment: Also: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: ohh I get it now, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is called "push-state routing" it makes use of the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

> Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the preceding JavaScript:
>
> This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html,
>   but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that
>   bar.html exists.
>
> Suppose now that the user now navigates to http://google.com, then
>   clicks back. At this point, the URL bar will display
>   http://mozilla.org/bar.html, and the page will get a popstate event
>   whose state object contains a copy of stateObj. The page itself will
>   look like foo.html, although the page might modify its contents during
>   the popstate event.
>
> If we click back again, the URL will change to
>   http://mozilla.org/foo.html, and the document will get another
>   popstate event, this time with a null state object. Here too, going
>   back doesn't change the document's contents from what they were in the
>   previous step, although the document might update its contents
>   manually upon receiving the popstate event.

Once we understood all this, we simply need to listen on the window's `popstate` events which will be trigger on every state change, be it triggered by clicks, pressing the browser back button and so on.